# Complex update using joins and group by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

This query selects ID's from two tables where there are exactly one to one name matches

```
SELECT d.guest_id, h.host_id
FROM `guest` AS g 
JOIN `guest_data` AS d 
    ON d.guest_id = g.guest_id 
JOIN host_data AS h 
    ON d.guest_nm = h.host_nm 
GROUP BY
    h.venue_nm 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Now I'm having trouble updating  `guest` table (g) to set the g.link_id = h.host_id

Basically I want to create a statement like

```
UPDATE `guest` AS g , `host` h
SET g.link_id = h.host_id
WHERE g.guest_id = ... AND h.host_id = ... the pairs in the previous statement
```

Comment: Can you give some details on what trouble you're having? error messages?

Comment: @kelloti: No error, I just don't know how to convert this SELECT statement into an UPDATE statement

Answer (score 6):

A problem you might be having is that you could have many host_data rows for each guest, so you have to use an aggregate function (I used max below) to get to the single row you want to pull a host_id from. I'm more of a SQL Server person, but I think this syntax is pretty close to what you'll use on MySQL. Here's my select:

```
SELECT g.link_id, 
    (
        SELECT MAX(h.host_id)
        FROM guest_data d
        INNER JOIN host_data h ON d.guest_nm=hhost_nm
        GROUP BY h.venue_nm
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) AS x
FROM guest g
WHERE g.guest_id IN 
(
    SELECT d.guest_id
    FROM guest_data d
    INNER JOIN host_data h ON d.guest_nm=hhost_nm
    GROUP BY h.venue_nm
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

After checking that the select returns the right result set you can easily convert that into an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE guest g
SET link_id=
    (
        SELECT MAX(h.host_id)
        FROM guest_data d
        INNER JOIN host_data h ON d.guest_nm=hhost_nm
        WHERE d.guest_id=g.guest_id
        GROUP BY h.venue_nm
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    )
WHERE g.guest_id IN 
(
    SELECT d.guest_id
    FROM guest_data d
    INNER JOIN host_data h ON d.guest_nm=hhost_nm
    GROUP BY h.venue_nm
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

I hope this is close enough to be of help...

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server, you would do something like

UPDATE guest
SET link_id = host_id
FROM guest g
...

I've never used mysql, so fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the syntax for this a bit, I decided to break up the operations and used the same SELECT query to INSERT INTO a temporary table.  Then I performed the UPDATE using typical JOIN syntax.

This has the added benefit of being able to verify the query results before pushing to your table.